# schedule (Python lib) - How to run a job in multiple certain minutes of hour

Tags: python, schedule

I am using [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) library for scheduling Python scripts.

What I want to implement is a job running on top and bottom of every hour (i.e. ...10:00, 10:30, 11:00...).

I have tried the follows:

- When I use it as `schedule.every(30).minutes.do(job)`, the time the job starts depends on when the program is started (If it is run on 10:17, it will run at 10:47, 11:17 etc.) which is not what I need.
- There is also an `schedule.every().hour.at(":30").do(job)` method supplied, but it does not span `:00`s.

So, I seek an idiomatic, or at least a neat, way to achieve it with this library. Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

An approach is to kill the last schedule process and begin a new one with a new time. In order to specify the next time, I implemented a not-so-neat function.

```
import schedule

# an arbitrary start time
start = '11:30'


def next_time(start):
    ''' This function gives the next time. eg '13:00'->'13:30', '24:30'->'01:00' '''
    comp = start.split(':')
    if '30' in comp[1]:
        comp[1] = '00'
        comp[0] = str(int(comp[0]) + 1)
    else:
        comp[1] = '30'
    if int(comp[0]) > 24:
        comp[0] = '01'
    return ':'.join(comp)


def job(time_now):
    print("The job has been done!")
    # kill the previous schedule, specified with a tag
    schedule.clear('previous')
    # the new time is calculated by next_time function
    next_point = next_time(time_now)
    # return a new one with the new time for the scheduled job
    return schedule.every().day.at(next_point).do(job, next_point).tag('previous')


# implementing the schedule for first time
schedule.every().day.at(start).do(job, start).tag('previous')


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```